# C# logic to implement foreach loop when check box is checked

Tags: c#, foreach

I have a checkBox in my Windows application called "Continuous". When user checks this and clicks "Process" button, application will process all the items in the listBox. However if user does not check this box it will only process the first one in the list.

In my Process method I want to write an if condition to check the checkBox checked and execute the foreach loop otherwise execute just the first item.

Here is my code

```
private void btnProcess_Clicl()
{

  bool bDone = false;

  while(!bDone)
  {

    LoadList(); //This will load the list from database into listBox

    if(listBox.items.Count > 0)
    {
      ProcessList();
    }

    if(!chkBox.Checked)
      bDone = true;

  }

}
```

I've implement the foreach loop to process list in ProcessList() method. Is there anyway to avoid executing LoadList() method from executing if the user checks continuous checkBox? LoadList() will populate the listBox from database.

Comment: Is the issue that you only want to try to `ProcessList()` once if the checkbox is checked, or is it that you want to avoid loading the entire list from the db if it isn't checked?

Comment: Be careful... it sounds like you want to modify the list you are looping over.  You can't do this inside of a foreach loop.

Comment: Why is your if(!chkBox.Checked) at the bottom? I don't really know what you are asking i'm afraid but without further explanation i'd guess you should be checking if that box is checked or not before doing anything.

Comment: Dan - I want to execute ProcessList() only once and after executing it once Iam checking if the user has clicked continuous or not. Depending on that I am exiting the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this

```
if( chkBox.Checked )
    ProcessList();
else
    ProcessOne();
```

Write the functions to do what you want

**update**

to avoid duplicating the processing code you could do something like

```
public void ProcessList()
{
    foreach( var item in list )
        ProcessOne( item );
}
```

Comment: So, this is like writing the code twice in ProcessList() and ProcessOne() method. Right?

Comment: I think this makes sense. I was thinking of a way not to write the code twice but I think there is no other way by looking at the answers.

Thanks.

Comment: @shanthiram you don't necessarily need to duplicate code.  see update incoming...

Answer (score 2):

Factoring is your friend.

```
void ProcessList(int start, int count) {
    for (int i=start; i < start + count; i++) {
        ProcessItem(i);
    }
}

void ProcessItem(int i) { // your code here
}

private void btnProcess_Click() {
   if (IsContinuous) {
      ProcessList(0, list.Count);
   }
   else {
       ProcessItem(0);
   }
}

private bool IsContinuous { get { return chkBox.Checked; } }
```

This will work for you but I don't especially like it since I think Process should be part of the list data structure itself and not my UI.  Model (and View) and Control should be separate (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

```
    Boolean doAllItems = chkBox.Checked;
    foreach(Object something in collection)
    {
        DoWork(something);
        if(!doAllItems)
            break;
    }
```